# Can the logrotate descriptor handle multiple wildcards?

Tags: logs, syslog, rsyslog, logrotate

For example, on a `syslog` collector, where remote `syslog` is coming into `/var/syslog/<host>/*.log`, can I have something like the following in my `logrotate` config:

```
/var/syslog/*/*.log {
    daily
    keep 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can and it works out of the box. See https://superuser.com/questions/255951/logrotate-configuration-file-syntax-multiple-wildcard-entries-possible

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: thanks. I collated your find and a colleague's reference into an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409367/6388)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to both a colleague and [Patrick Mevzek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/211833/patrick-mevzek) for [finding](https://superuser.com/q/255951/978) the [answer](https://www.rfaircloth.com/2016/05/16/building-reliable-rsyslogd-infrastructure-splunk) to this question.

Quoting from [rfaircloth.com](https://www.rfaircloth.com/2016/05/16/building-reliable-rsyslogd-infrastructure-splunk):

> Create log rotation configuration `/etc/logrotate.d/splunk-syslog`:

```
/var/splunk-syslog/*/*.log { 
    daily
    compress
    delaycompress
    rotate 4 
    ifempty
    maxage 7
    nocreate
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd-ng.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true 
    endscript
 }
```

This is OOTB functionality as of at least RHEL/CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 16 LTS.